# How/where to add additional stylesheet to WP

Tags: css

I am rebuilding my website and want to use a font I purchased from MyFonts.com and need to add `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MyFontsWebfontsKit.css">`, but I don't know where or how this should be added.

I am a WP novice so need step-by-step easy to understand instructions please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WordPress API provides the functions [`wp_enqueue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) and [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) for including stylesheets and JavaScript.

These functions should be used instead of hardcoding style or script tags within HTML.

```
// Runs wpse_enqueue_styles() on the wp_enqueue_scripts() hook.
// (Yes, we're enqueuing a stylesheet here, but the proper hook is wp_enqueue_scripts.
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_enqueue_styles' );
function wpse_enqueue_styles() {

        wp_enqueue_style(
            // Handle
            'example-font',

            // Source (URL) for stylesheet.
            // Here, the stylesheet resides at /theme-name/css/MyFontsWebfontsKit.css
            get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/MyFontsWebfontsKit.css',

            // Dependencies for stylesheet. None in this case.
            array()
        );
}
```

Place the code above in your theme's `functions.php` file. Note that the "wpse_" prefix should be changed to match whatever is used by your theme.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Dave. I forgot to mention I am building my site offline using wamp. Does this matter? I STILL can't get this to load my choice of font. It's driving me crazy.

Comment: Using Wamp should not matter. (I tested the code I posted using Xampp.) First make sure that the stylesheet is being loaded using your browser's developer tools. You might want to try a test stylesheet that contains something like `* {  color: purple !important; }`. Once you've verified that the test styles work, then try working with the actual font styles.

Comment: Thank you again for your help Dave! I wound up putting their CSS in MY CSS file and it worked perfectly. I'm pretty sure I had the links wrong doing it the other way though.

Comment: You got it! I'm glad that the solution worked, and thank you for following up.